# Microformat (hCard, hCalendar) parsing services

Tags: parsing, service, microformats, handlers

I'm about to write my own .ashx handler to receive hCard data and return a properly-formatted VCF file and - when I get around to it - to handle hCalendar events as well.  I know the Microsoft Oomph project does something very similar (in fact, I plan to base much of my work off that service).

Are there a range of open services available that do the same thing?  Is it worth doing my own (if not purely for the learning experience)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>http://suda.co.uk/projects/microformats/hcard/</del>[http://h2vx.com/vcf/](http://h2vx.com/vcf)